# Dynamic variables incrementation in javascript for photoshop

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to add three text layers to photoshop (possibly more later) and there are 3 bits of information that i want changed in each so i thought a loop would be ideal.

```
// create a new text layers and add them to the document
var newTextLayer1 = docRef.artLayers.add();
var newTextLayer2 = docRef.artLayers.add();
var newTextLayer3 = docRef.artLayers.add();

// positions of layers
var pos1 = Array(0,100);
var pos2 = Array(0,200);
var pos3 = Array(0,300);

// store text in variables
var row1 = "1st row";
var row2 = "2nd row";
var row3 = "3rd row";

//loop for text-layers settings
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
     newTextLayer+i.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
     newTextLayer+i.textItem.size = 12;
     newTextLayer+i.textItem.contents = row+i;
     newTextLayer+i.textItem.font = "Courier";
     newTextLayer+i.textItem.color = textCol;
     newTextLayer+i.textItem.position = pos+i;
}`
```

I know this doesnt work but could someone guide me to the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the specific photoshop api - however I believe your problem could be solved by storing your nextTextLayer, text, and positions objects in an array.

```
var layers = [
  docRef.artLayers.add(),
  docRef.artLayers.add(),
  docRef.artLayers.add()
];

// Using array literals
var positions = [
  [0, 100],
  [0, 200],
  [0, 300]
];

var texts = [
  '1st row',
  '2nd row',
  '3rd row'
];

// now you can access each value correctly by supplying the current
// value of the loop counter variable.

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  layers[i].kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
  layers[i].textItem.size = 12;
  layers[i].textItem.contents = texts[i];
  layers[i].textItem.font = 'Courier';
  layers[i].textItem.color = textCol;
  layers[i].textItem.position = positions[i];
}
```

Since javascript arrays are just objects with numerical indexes, you can easily access the values stored (which can be other objects) from within a loop.